# How to access shared static data from multiple service

Tags: wcf, shared-data

I've build wcf service under IIS 7.

I've problem with shared data.

I get error in runtime, when i try to access static data from other service.

Service 1

```
[ServiceContract(Name="ServiceChat", CallbackContract=typeof(IChatCallback))]
public ChatService { 
     static int counter;
     ...
}
```

Service 2

```
[ServiceContract(Name="ServiceAvatar", CallbackContract=typeof(IAvatarCallback))]
public AvatarService {
     [OperationContract] 
     public int Test {
          return ChatService.counter; // Throw error
     }
     ...
}
```

Comment: any idea how to shared data accross multiple service ?

Comment: Database? Third service the other two call?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanindg .
You want to share a centralized static data among different resourses.

Why dont you decorate your WCF contract with 
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]

This will create only one session and all the clients are accessing your services through the same session.

So its like they all get the same source .

Hope this helps.